# Sending Emails using smtp server host c# mvc web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

Can anyone help me in fixing this issue. I know it was already asked but none of those answers helped me as I tried all of them. Anyway I hope a new solution will come up which is going to fix my problem.

It works & sends emails when I try to send emails using host `smtp.gmail.com` but can't send emails using host `smtpout.secureserver.net`. I have a valid smtp server account too.
The exception I got is here:

> Unable to read data from the transport connection: `net_io_connectionclosed`...

web.config:

```xml
<appSettings>
    <add key="fromMail" value="notification@abc.com" />
    <add key="fromPassword" value="abc" />
    <add key="smtpHost" value="smtpout.secureserver.net" />
    <add key="smtpPort" value="465" />
</appSettings>
```

I also tried this in web.config:

```xml
<system.net>
   <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="notification@abc.com">
         <network host="smtpout.secureserver.net" port="25" userName="notification@abc.com" password="abc"/>
      </smtp>
</mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

but no luck at all...:(

Code:

```
public static sendMail(String toAddress, string body, string subject,string bcc,string cc)
{
       String fromAddress = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["fromMail"];
        String fromPassword = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["fromPassword"];
        String smtpHost = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["smtpHost"];
        String smtpPort = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["smtpPort"];            

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Port = Convert.ToInt32(smtpPort);
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Host = smtpHost;
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(fromAddress, fromPassword);

        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress);
        mail.Subject = subject;
        mail.Body = body;
        mail.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

        if(attachments != null && attachments.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach(var attach in attachments)
            {
                mail.Attachments.Add(attach);
            }
        }

        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(bcc))
            mail.Bcc.Add(bcc);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cc))
            mail.CC.Add(cc);
        try
        {
            client.Send(mail);
        }
        catch (SmtpException exception)
        {
           // Console.WriteLine("Mail Sending Failed");
            return "Mail Sending Failed"+ exception.Message;
        }
        return "ok";
    }

}
```

Please help me guys...Thanks in advance...

Also someone in forums got the same error. He said that the problem is with his SMTP server. If the same problem in my case, how would I know that the problem lies within my SMTP server?

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing my codes with you as i tried all of them too.

Here is my configuration in app.config file

```
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="xxx@gmail.com">
    <network defaultCredentials="false" enableSsl="true" host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" userName="xxx@gmail.com" password="xxx" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

And here is my c# codes (this is a console application)

```
Console.Write("Sending test mail...");
        using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                client.Send("ramazandonmez@yandex.com.tr", "ramazan.donmez@euromsg.com", "Test Message Subject", "Test Message Body");
                Console.WriteLine("test mail sended");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

I hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for the response.It works for smtp.gamil.com but not working for host "smtpout.secureserver.net". I clearly stated this in my question...

Comment: sorry.. firstly, you should check accessibility to the host and port using telnet. and then you should verify that user and password... you can find an example about the telnet smtp connection commands: http://www.kongtechnology.com/2008/01/27/smtp-authentication-and-send-emails-using-telnet/